# Can Unity render just 4 sides of a skybox?

Tags: unity-game-engine

In my game I don't need the top and bottom sides of skyboxes, so I removed them from the material. However, according to Frame Debugger, Unity still renders all 6 sides, even though they're never seen and should be occluded. Is there a way to ensure only four sides get rendered?

Answer (score 0):

This is usually done via a certain shader like e.g. the default [6-sided Skybox](https://github.com/TwoTailsGames/Unity-Built-in-Shaders/blob/master/DefaultResourcesExtra/Skybox.shader).

What you can see there is that it contains 6 passes for the 6 sides.

Something you have to render at these points so I think you can't just remove the passes but I guess you could probably create one for only 4-sides which simply returns only a simple color and skipping the texture like e.g.

```c#
Shader "Custom/Skybox4"
{
    Properties
    {
        _Tint ("Tint Color", Color) = (.5, .5, .5, .5)
        [Gamma] _Exposure ("Exposure", Range(0, 8)) = 1.0
        _Rotation ("Rotation", Range(0, 360)) = 0
        [NoScaleOffset] _FrontTex ("Front [+Z]   (HDR)", 2D) = "grey" {}
        [NoScaleOffset] _BackTex ("Back [-Z]   (HDR)", 2D) = "grey" {}
        [NoScaleOffset] _LeftTex ("Left [+X]   (HDR)", 2D) = "grey" {}
        [NoScaleOffset] _RightTex ("Right [-X]   (HDR)", 2D) = "grey" {}
        _TopBottomColor ("Top Bottom Fill Color", Color) = (0, 0, 0, 0)
    }

    SubShader
    {
        Tags
        {
            "Queue"="Background" "RenderType"="Background" "PreviewType"="Skybox"
        }
        Cull Off ZWrite Off

        CGINCLUDE
        #include "UnityCG.cginc"

        half4 _Tint;
        half _Exposure;
        float _Rotation;

        float3 RotateAroundYInDegrees(float3 vertex, float degrees)
        {
            float alpha = degrees * UNITY_PI / 180.0;
            float sina, cosa;
            sincos(alpha, sina, cosa);
            float2x2 m = float2x2(cosa, -sina, sina, cosa);
            return float3(mul(m, vertex.xz), vertex.y).xzy;
        }

        struct appdata_t
        {
            float4 vertex : POSITION;
            float2 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;
            UNITY_VERTEX_INPUT_INSTANCE_ID
        };

        struct v2f
        {
            float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
            float2 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;
            UNITY_VERTEX_OUTPUT_STEREO
        };

        v2f vert(appdata_t v)
        {
            v2f o;
            UNITY_SETUP_INSTANCE_ID(v);
            UNITY_INITIALIZE_VERTEX_OUTPUT_STEREO(o);
            float3 rotated = RotateAroundYInDegrees(v.vertex, _Rotation);
            o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(rotated);
            o.texcoord = v.texcoord;
            return o;
        }

        half4 skybox_frag(v2f i, sampler2D smp, half4 smpDecode)
        {
            half4 tex = tex2D(smp, i.texcoord);
            half3 c = DecodeHDR(tex, smpDecode);
            c = c * _Tint.rgb * unity_ColorSpaceDouble.rgb;
            c *= _Exposure;
            return half4(c, 1);
        }
        ENDCG

        Pass
        {
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            #pragma target 2.0
            sampler2D _FrontTex;
            half4 _FrontTex_HDR;
            half4 frag(v2f i) : SV_Target { return skybox_frag(i, _FrontTex, _FrontTex_HDR); }
            ENDCG
        }
        Pass
        {
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            #pragma target 2.0
            sampler2D _BackTex;
            half4 _BackTex_HDR;
            half4 frag(v2f i) : SV_Target { return skybox_frag(i, _BackTex, _BackTex_HDR); }
            ENDCG
        }
        Pass
        {
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            #pragma target 2.0
            sampler2D _LeftTex;
            half4 _LeftTex_HDR;
            half4 frag(v2f i) : SV_Target { return skybox_frag(i, _LeftTex, _LeftTex_HDR); }
            ENDCG
        }
        Pass
        {
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            #pragma target 2.0
            sampler2D _RightTex;
            half4 _RightTex_HDR;
            half4 frag(v2f i) : SV_Target { return skybox_frag(i, _RightTex, _RightTex_HDR); }
            ENDCG
        }
        Pass
        {
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            half4 _TopBottomColor;
            half4 frag(v2f i) : SV_Target { return _TopBottomColor; }
            ENDCG
        }
        Pass
        {
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            half4 _TopBottomColor;
            half4 frag(v2f i) : SV_Target { return _TopBottomColor; }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

Which looks like this

[image]

(Skybox source: [Emil Persson, aka Humus](http://www.humus.name/index.php?page=Textures&start=0))

This won't fully remove the rendering pass but should be at least faster.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to completely remove the rendering pass? They are all separate batches, that's what concerns me. However, I believe Unity will combine the top and bottom side with your shader, resulting in one less batch.